# How to add msg to a variable that is undefined?

Tags: javascript, variables, null, undefined

Hopefully I am asking the correct question. I want to add a msg that states "Please Enter Item weight" if the user clicks the button without inputting anything in the text field. 
I tried multiple ways but can't seem to get it. A msg comes up saying "undefined" instead of what I want it to say/show.

```
    if( typeof(weight) == 'undefined' || weight == null) {

    msg = "<div id='error'>Please Enter Item Weight</div>";
    }
```

Comment: It highly possible that the condition was not true and hence the value of msg is undefined. It would be great if you could create a jsfiddle and we'll all be more helpful :)

Comment: @IzaazYunus Here you go :) http://jsfiddle.net/AvjS5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change weight definition to something like this:

```
var weight = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight").value || 0);
```

When you try to convert a string to a number using `parseInt` it will return `NaN` if you pass empty string (when there is no user input). So in this case simple fallback to 0 `value || 0` can fix it.

Another option is to use `+` operator to cast to a number:

```
var weight = +document.getElementById("weight").value;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AvjS5/1/

Comment: Perfect! Just the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
 if( weight == 'undefined' || weight == null) {

    msg = "<div id='error'>Please Enter Item Weight</div>";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do is, use the isNaN function. When you try to do a parseInt on an invalid string, the value returned is NaN a.k.a Not a Number.

```
var weight = parseInt( document.getElementById("weight").value );
if(isNaN(weight)){
    msg="<div>Hello</div>"
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AvjS5/2/)

Also, you haven't added logic to see if none of the option buttons were checked.

Comment: Thanks Izaaz, but dfsq's answer was exactly what I was looking for.